# Grails 3 upgrade Test issues

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-plugin

When I run tests with the Build-Test-Data plugin in grails 3 I see the following error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com...Item.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: last(), wait(), any(), saveAll([Ljava.lang.Object;), saveAll(java.lang.Iterable), last(java.lang.String)
```

This is typically around a `.save()` or a `.build()` I am not a test guru so anyone know what is up?

**Update**

The example looks like this...

```
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build

@Build(Author)
class AuthorUnitTests {

    void testAuthorStuff() {
        def author = Author.build()
        ...
    }

}
```

My Code looks like...

```
@TestFor(Item)
@Build([Item])
class ItemSpec extends Specification
{
  ...
  def "Blah Blah"() {
        given:
            Item i = Item.build(id: 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is a unit test then `@Build(Item)` should be used at class level as shown in the documentation of the plugin.

Comment: I am a bit confused can you point to the part to which you are referring? I see appendum

Comment: With the above update it is clear that you are using `@Build`. It should work. Also do you have to assign the `id` manually?

Answer (score 0):

Below unit test passes in Grails 3.1.1:

```
package com.example

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.buildtestdata.mixin.Build

@TestFor(Item)
@Build(Item)
class ItemSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        expect:
        Item.build(name: 'Test').name == 'Test'
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:build-test-data:3.0.0'
```

Make sure to build/compile the app once the plugin GAV added to `build.gradle`:

```
gradlew build
```

should do.

Comment: I am using grails 3.0.11 but I can double check